# How can I insert vertical text spanning multiple rows into a table?

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx

I would like to add a column to my table that looks like the right most column in the included picture.

[image]

As of now, I am using `tabularx` to create the table

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|}
    \hline 1) No. of Distinct MMSI Detected & 1 \\ 
    \hline 2) Average Time Between Messages (moving ships)& 1 \\ 
    \hline 3) No. of Dopplegangers &  1\\ 
    \hline 4) Total No. of Anomalies &1  \\ 
    \hline 5) List of Anomalies by MMSI &  See Spreadsheet\\ 
    \hline 6) Avergae Mad Time Between Messages from Same Ship & 1 \\ 
    \hline 7) Average Number of Messages per MMSI per Hour  &1  \\ 
    \hline 8) Average Age of Messages on Receipt& 1 \\ 
    \hline 9) Average Age of Messages at System Observation Time&  1\\ 
    \hline 10) Average Dead Reckoning Error for Moving Ships &1  \\ 
    \hline  11) Age Distribution Chart& See Figure  \\
    \hline 12)  Position Error Distribution Chart& See Figure\\
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  Is `tabularx` the right package?

Comment: I believe you mean the column `left` of the data table, with rotated text?

Comment: correct, sorry.

Comment: Use \multirow (multirow package) \rotatebox (graphicx package) and \parbox.  It is easier to determine the \parbox width by trial and error, but it can be computed using \savebox and a partial tabular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\newcounter{rownum}

\begin{document}

     \begin{table*}
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont aligned with data}
    \settowidth{\rotheadsize}{Minimum employees}
    \setcounter{rownum}{0}
        \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{1.25cm}| >{\refstepcounter{rownum}\eqmakebox[N] [r]{\therownum)\enspace}}X|c|}
        \hline
    & No. of Distinct MMSI Detected & 1 \\
        \cline{2-3}
    & Average Time Between Messages (moving ships)& 1 \\
        \cline{2-3}
    \multirowcell{-3}[-4.5ex]{\hspace*{-.6em}\turnbox{90}{\thead{MMSI\\Statistical\\analysis}}}& No. of Dopplegangers & 1\\
        \hline
     & Total No. of Anomalies &1 \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \multirowcell{-2}[-4.5ex]{\hspace*{-1.8em}\turnbox{90}{\thead{Anomaly\\Detection \\reports}}} & List of Anomalies by MMSI & See Spreadsheet\\
     \hline
    & Average Mad Time Between Messages from Same Ship & 1 \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Average Number of Messages per MMSI per Hour &1 \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Average Age of Messages on Receipt& 1 \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Average Age of Messages at System Observation Time& 1\\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Average Dead Reckoning Error for Moving Ships &1 \\
    \cline{2-3}
     & Age Distribution Chart& See Figure \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \multirow{-4}{*}[0.25ex]{\hspace*{2.8em}\turnbox{90}{\thead{Systemic Quality\\analysis}}} & Position Error Distribution Chart& See Figure \\
     \hline
    \end{tabularx}
        \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create that tabular with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. With that environment, you merge cells vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block` and the key `hvlines` will draw all the rules excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

Moreover, there is a built-in LaTeX counter `iRow` for the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c>{\makebox[7mm][r]{{\arabic{iRow})}\enspace}}lc}[hvlines]
\Block{3-1}<\rotate>{MMSI\\Statistical\\analysis} 
& No. of Distinct MMSI Detected & 1 \\
& Average Time Between Messages (moving ships)& 1 \\
& No. of Dopplegangers & 1\\
\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{Anomaly\\Detection \\reports} 
& Total No. of Anomalies &1 \\
& List of Anomalies by MMSI & See Spreadsheet\\
\Block{7-1}<\rotate>{Systemic Quality\\analysis} 
& Average Mad Time Between Messages from Same Ship & 1 \\
& Average Number of Messages per MMSI per Hour &1 \\
& Average Age of Messages on Receipt& 1 \\
& Average Age of Messages at System Observation Time& 1\\
& Average Dead Reckoning Error for Moving Ships &1 \\
& Age Distribution Chart& See Figure \\
& Position Error Distribution Chart& See Figure \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]